# Path Functions & State Functions, in Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

I had found one question, while practicing Thermodynamics, and I am confused to see it.
(Check it Below)

[image]

As you can see, here the correct answer is Temperature. But, I also know that the Energy is also a State Function, but it says incorrect answer, when I click it. And, when I searched on my internet, they all are saying only about Temperature, No one is discussing that why Energy is not the Correct one.   *Please Tell Me, that Energy is State or Path Function, or there is some other Concept that I'm missing out here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are talking about energies in Thermodynamics, we need to distinguish several types of it. There is the internal energy $U$, which is actually closely related to the temperature and thus similarly conserves in the process independent of its path. However, there are also the work $W$ and the heat $Q$, and those actually depend on the path. Generally, we may recall the first law of thermodynamics: $\Delta U = Q-W$, so while $\Delta U$ is always zero independent of the shape of the path, this doesn't mean that $Q$ and $W$ are as. And since it's not clearly stated what is meant by "Energy" among $\Delta U$, $Q$, and $W$, we can't say that this quantity is independent of the path.

Comment: Work and heat are not energy. They are means for transferring energy and are path dependent.

Comment: I agree, but we still wouldn't be right to call internal energy of the system just as "energy"

Comment: Yes, but when you say work and heat are energy it promulgates misunderstanding the meaning of heat and work. That's my only point.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with you. Energy is considered a property of a system, just like temperature, pressure, etc. and is path independent. But usually it it referred to as  "internal energy" which is the total kinetic plus potential energy that something possesses at the microscopic (atomic/molecular) level and thus is also independent of an external (to the system) frame of reference.

The only possible thing they may have had in mind, and I'm just guessing, is that an object can also possess energy that is frame of reference dependent, i.e., its "external" energy. For example, the kinetic energy of a baseball in motion depends on the frame of reference of the observer and its gravitational potential energy depends on where zero potential energy is assigned. But even then, IMO, calling the baseball energy "path dependent" would be a stretch.

Hope this helps.